# Backbone.js - extending a model(in collection) using parse method not getting the updated collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

In my app, i have multiple page, i do have a plain model, from the plain model i am extending further models according to the pages using the collection's `parse` method.

after doing this, still i am not getting the returned collection, instead i am getting just the object what i am retrieving from the backend.

myview code :

```
 define([
        "jquery",
        "backbone",
        "models/model",
        "collection/dashBoardcollection",
        "views/navi/naviView",
        "views/dashBoard/myTaskView",
        ],function ($,Backbone,model,collection,naviView,myTaskView) {

    var dashBoardView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:$("div.contentwrapper"),
        events:{
            "click h2" : "tileleDispaly"
        },
        initialize:function(){
            this.$el.html(this.template);
            this.c = collection;
            this.listenTo(this.c, 'sync', this.logCollection);
            this.c.fetch();
        },
        logCollection:function(){
             console.log(this.c);
//not getting the collection shows array length as 1
            },
            tileleDispaly:function(e){
                var tittle = $(e.target).text();
                new myTaskView().showTitle(tittle);
            }
        });

    return dashBoardView;

})
```

my collection code :

```
   define(["backbone","models/model"], function (Backbone,model) {

    var titleModel = model.extend({
        "title" : "no title assigned"
    })

    var slideModel = model.extend({
        "slide" : "no title assigned"
    })

    var rowModel = model.extend({
        "title" : "no title assigned",
        "text"  : "no text",
        "date"  : "define date"
    })

    var optionModel = model.extend({
        "show" : "no title assigned"
    })

    var dashBoardCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url:"js/dashBoard.json",
        model:model,
        initialize:function(model,options){

        },
        parse:function(response){

            var that = this;

                var x = [];
// update 1. pushing all models to x array

            _.each(response.DashBoard, function(obj){

                if(obj.hasOwnProperty("title")){

                    x.push(new titleModel(obj));

                }else if (obj.hasOwnProperty("widget")){

                    _.each(obj.widget, function(m){
                        x.push(new slideModel(obj));
                    })

                }else if (obj.hasOwnProperty("activity")){

                    _.each(obj.activity, function(va){

                        if(va.hasOwnProperty("rows")){

                            _.each(va.rows, function(row){
                                x.push(new rowModel(row));
                            })

                        }else if (va.hasOwnProperty("option")){

                            _.each(va.option, function(option){
                                x.push(new optionModel(option));
                            })

                        }

                    })

                }

            })

            this.add(x);
//update 2. adding the models to collection

                console.log(this);
// console works fine shows the array length as 12.

                return this;
//returning to view.. 

            }
        });

    return new dashBoardCollection;

})
```

but my view hasn't brings any models.. from collection, what is wrong here..? or my way of approach is wrong? any one help me to sort this issue..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the response in done is not a Collection. It is just an object from the response..

Log c which is an updated collection

```
c.done(function(data){
    console.log(c); //Will be the updated collection
})
```

Also listening to the event is a cleaner approach than using promised methods.

```
initialize: function() {
       this.$el.html(this.template);
       this.c = collection;
       this.listenTo(this.c, 'sync', this.logCollection);

       this.c.fetch(); //fetching the data
},
logCollection: function() {
    console.log(this.c); // This will log the collection
}
```

Comment: Hi Sushanth, i updated my question, still i am getting issue. in the collection part i am getting all models, but in the view part (after fetch) i am not getting the models.. some how the view part not properly fetching the data..

Comment: can you post a small sample of response that you get from the server

Comment: I am using json file.. when i console in the collection i am getting the length, but not in view.. still let me put all my code in to fiddle and update you

Comment: for the idea purpose i updated in to jsfiddle.. here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/nukRb/

Comment: when i am getting the models without any issue in collection, is it still i need to give the id? let try that. but i understand the issue is the collection result not properly received by view..

Comment: I am trying to see what is happening when a fetch occurs.. Cause when I add them explicitly calling parse it seems to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/nukRb/2/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34672/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-sushanth)